# Getting GCM Registration ID using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an ASP.net MVC server from where I want to send push notifications to my Android App. I have already implemented `Firebase Messaging` in the app and the notifications are working fine when sent from Firebase dashboard.

I have tried sending push notification using the server by sending a post request, but the request requires a `to` field. Earlier we used to send `registration id` provided by `GCM` there. Now since Firebase is handling it, how can I fetch the registration id to be put in the to field using Firebase SDK in Android?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Hi and thanks for using Firebase Cloud Messaging!

You can fetch the registration-id calling:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

Differently from the GCM sdk, the new library automatically takes care of fetching the token as soon as possible, and then it caches it locally.

The above method will return the token, if available, or `null` if the fetching phase is still in progress.

You can use the callback `onTokenRefresh()` to be notified when the token is available or has been rotated.

```
public class InstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        sendRegistrationToMyServer(refreshedToken);
    }
}
```

More info here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've missed this part in the doc. Trying it now.

Comment: is the registration token and device id are the same ?

Comment: My android application api developer asks me to send him the registartion token and device id but as we look in the code we are just reciving a single token thats it