# Where Firebase stored ID's every subscribed device?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

My app is subscribing to Firebase Cloud Messaging. I want to have get all devices tokens whose are subscribing. Where can I find them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting GCM Registration ID using Firebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37329917/getting-gcm-registration-id-using-firebase)

Comment: I want to get this token from Firebase Console. Maybe can I add this token to database on Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no API to retrieve all the Registration tokens for your app from the Server side or from the Firebase Console. It's the developer's (you) responsibility to send and store the Registration tokens to your App Server, which is generated from the Client App side.

<sub>From my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43061094/4625829).</sub>